# Invoke a unix shell from java program?read and write a steady stream of data to and from a unix pipe from java program

Tags: java, unix, named-pipes

I have 2 questions

1) how do I i invoke a unix shell from a java.runtime library to run a command like this

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);

cat alias > bias

2) How can I read and write to a unix pipe a steady stream of data from java.
Do i have to make all the system calls like open read write to a pipe

I basically want to replicate this command

cat alias > bias

where the steady stream of data will be come from  java program to bias and not cat alias.

Comment: You can try read this http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ">" directly in a Runtime.exec() command. It won't have the expected effect, and will not redirect the output to the file.

You have to get the input stream of your process and redirect it to the file to write:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cat", "alias"});
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("yourFile");
// Write in into fos...
// handle the process streams
```

I don't detail the writing method but:

- you have to handle the exceptions (IO)
- you have to consume (at least to close) all the process streams (error, input, output).

Comment: *"You can't use ">" in a Runtime.exec() command"*: Yes, you can. Why do you think you cannot do it?

Comment: @Grodriguez: I believe he wanted to explain that if you put ">" into a Runtime.exec() command, it will not have the effect it would have in a Unix shell. Of course you can use ">" as a regular character, or invoke /bin/sh as in your answer and pass ">" to it.

Comment: If that's what he meant he should have said so. Let's not second-guess shall we?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say that the ">" character doesn't have the expected comportement when used directly in "Runtime.exec()".Edited

Comment: @Benoit: It *will* have the same effect as it would in a Unix shell, as long as you are actually executing a Unix shell in `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: Yes, but in my example code, I do NOT execute a Unix shell, but only the "cat" command. So, for redirecting the output, I need to use the process streams. I prefer using java stuff rather than system stuff when I can.

Answer (score 6):

Since JDK7, there is a convinience way to do this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cat", "alias");
File bias = new File("bias");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(bias));
pb.start();
```

Reference: [ProcessBuilder#redirectOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File))

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke a Unix shell like you would invoke any other program. Use the `-c` option to pass the command to run as a parameter. Also make sure to use the `exec(String[])` method, and not `exec(String)`, to avoid the command being tokenized the wrong way:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/cat alias > bias"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

To read and write from/to the process, get the input, output, and error streams from the `Process` instance you just created:

```
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
```

Then read from/write to these streams as usual.

Note that streams are named relative to the Java application. Anything written to the `OutputStream` is piped to the standard input of the process you created. Anything written by the process to stdout/stderr is piped to the `InputStream`s obtained from `p.getInputStream()` and `p.getErrorStream()` respectively.

Reference: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html